# Diagonal lines in table cell on mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax

> [Tables of numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/tables-of-numbers)

Is it possible to put a "x\y" style legend in one cell (maybe be made up of several cells) of a table? It would be great to make the 'x' slightly lower while the 'y' slight higher.

Please see the picture below for illustration:

[image: XY_style]

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Maybe you can produce some hack to have something that looks similar, but MathJaX is not designed for this, and you're better off using a dedicated program to produce something like that. And in fact you probably need to consider very seriously whether it's indispensable to produce a table like that -- I honestly doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update. Changed `\stackrel` to `\overset`.

To get

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
  x\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 \hline
  4 & 4 & 8 & 12 \\ 
 \hline
  5 & 5 & 10 & 15 \\ 
 \hline
\end{array}

insert $x\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large y}{\phantom{l}}$ in the table top left corner, whose code is

`x\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large y}{\phantom{l}}`.

The table code is

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
  x\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 \hline
  4 & 4 & 8 & 12 \\ 
 \hline
  5 & 5 & 10 & 15 \\ 
 \hline
\end{array}
```

Comment: It is a tricky answer, but It's better then nothing

Comment: Just btw.: has `stackrel` advantages over `overset` ?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms No, I don't think so. In this respect I've adapted from a question and an answer from TEX.stackexchange.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms [`\stackrel` is obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/14965), one should always use `\overset` and `\underset`, at least in LaTeX. Maybe in MathJaX they are implemented identically though.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I've changed `\stackrel` to `\overset`.

Comment: @Nehorai I've changed `\stackrel` to `\overset`.